# Can you use the preposition "into" with "connected?

Tags: prepositions

Can you use the preposition "into" with "connected"?

Here's the sentence:

"When social data is connected into the platform, it's able to interact with all other data in a unified cross-channel environment."

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=connected+into&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconnected%20into%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Data is usually something that is *acted upon* by other components of a system. You may be giving it too much agency here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no doubt that "connected into" can be used in certain contexts: [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=connected+into&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconnected%20into%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cconnected%20into%3B%2Cc0), [connected into](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22connected%20into%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).

As for "connection into *a platform*" that is another matter; it is usual to connect circuits to other circuits and you might also say "connected into" occasionally, although this is not at all common for circuits ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=connect+the+circuit+into%2Cconnect+the+circuit+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconnect%20the%20circuit%20to%3B%2Cc0)). The idea of connecting *into* or *to* a program does not seem right.

[ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Dnfxyqdz3BQC&pg=PA128&dq=%22connected+into%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwis2d28ydPtAhVnxYUKHbOmAZIQ6AEwKnoECDoQAg#v=onepage&q=%22connected%20into%22&f=false) Network card A network card or NIC ( network interface card ) enables a computer to be connected into a LAN ( local area network ).

When it comes to data, the concept of connection does not seem proper. Are commonly used the phrases "[the data is fed to/into](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+data+is+fed+to%2Cthe+data+is+fed+into&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20data%20is%20fed%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20data%20is%20fed%20into%3B%2Cc0) and  "[feed (the) data to/into sth](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=feed+the+data+to%2Cfeed+the+data+into&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfeed%20the%20data%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfeed%20the%20data%20into%3B%2Cc0)" ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=feed+data+to%2C+feed+data+into&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfeed%20data%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfeed%20data%20into%3B%2Cc0)). When dealing with programs, "to feed" is a better term. The following formulation is much preferable, I believe.

- "When social data is fed to the platform, it's able to interact with all other data in a unified cross-channel environment."

Answer (score 0):

A child of the last century, to whom *channel* and *platform* originally had rather different meanings, I have to dig into definitions to justify this objectively. I also beg forgiveness for treating *data* as plural rather than singular, although this is irrelevant to the answer.

*Into* is a useful preposition. One of its meanings is:

> into = to the inside or middle of a place, container, area, etc.
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/into)

as such, *into* has  sense of direction to it: from outside towards the inside.

*Platform* is used:

> =  Operating System; also the computer architecture and equipment using a particular operating system>
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/platform)

> = the type of computer system or smartphone you are using, in relation to the type of software (= computer programs) you can use on it
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/platform)

> channel = a means of communication or expression: such as a path along which information (such as data or music) in the form of an electrical signal passes
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/channel)

The construction is now clear. Social data flow in a channel and are connected to the platform and to the software embedded in the operating system (OS) by input routines and hence they flow towards the interior of the software (they are input, to be processed by the algorithms that are embedded in the OS and the architecture).

When they are processed by the algorithms they are processed together with other data that were input from other channels. The network of channels is unified by the architecture of the OS and its software routines and it is within that architecture and its routines that all data are handled together.

The use of *into* rather than *in* is useful to give the sense of direction and flow so useful to understand the concept of what is happening.